# access xperia z1 compact with broken screen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, recovery-mode, broken-screen, sony-xperia-z1

My Xperia Z1 compact runs CM12. Unfortunately it has fallen on its bottom left corner and the touch screen is completely unresponsive. The cost of a replacement screen is more than a new phone with similar specs so I bought a new phone.

Now I am trying to get access to some files that are on the internal SD card (loads of contacts that I don't want to re-type, but also the latest photos).

The phone has Cyanogen recovery on it so I booted into that, and on my computer ran adb:

```
# adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
```

but then

```
# adb devices
List of devices attached 
CB5A24NPRD      offline
```

which I cannot seem to change. Because I cannot use the touch screen, the only way to control the phone is in recovery mode with the volume and on/off keys. Is the best thing to do just to dismantle it and get the internal SD card? If it is a physical card then that may be the best way to go?

Comment: Only the touchscreen is dead or is the display dead too?

Comment: The display works -- I still see the keypad for unlocking my SIM; the problem is the touch screen. I think the crack from left to right makes localisation impossible.

Comment: You should try connecting a mouse via OTG. Once you enable USB debugging, photos and files can be pulled via adb. For contacts you will have to export to Sdcard before pulling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try connecting a mouse via OTG. Once you enable USB debugging, photos and files can be pulled via adb. For contacts you will have to export to Sdcard before pulling.

Comment: Finally had time to try out the OTG solution which worked straight away! After setting up the phone I could pull it all to the computer with ADB.